# Showing ellipse type of text in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, central-administration, user-profile-property, term-set

I have created SharePoint term set field and mapped to profile ask me about section.if i select more then 5 terms it shows ellipse type of tags when displaying.it converts automatically . i have not included any of the css in it.
please suggest some idea to resolve this ellipse values.

Comment: I got resolved by changing the web part properties.

Comment: Please post your solution in details as an answer to be helpful for all users. Thanks!